# Table caption label format as "Table L-1."

Tags: formatting, captions

I want to make a new table caption as

> **Table L-1.** This is a table caption

Currently, I am using the below code, but it has large margin between character and number as **"Table L- 1"**. Could you help me to make a professional table caption as above requirement

This is my code

```
\captionsetup[table]{labelfont={bf},labelformat={default},labelsep=period,name={Table L-}}
\begin{table}
\captionsetup{labelfont={bf}}
\caption{This is a table caption}
\begin{tabular}{@{} lcccccc @{}} % suppress vertical whitespace at start and end
\end{tabular}
\label{labelhere}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Change format only in caption label

You can make use of `\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat` from the [`caption`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package, see section 4 of the [`caption` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf).

You can use either

```
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{nospace}{#1#2}
\captionsetup[table]{labelfont=bf,name=Table L-,labelformat=nospace,labelsep=period}
```

or simply

```
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{tablel}{#1L-#2}
\captionsetup[table]{labelfont=bf,labelformat=tablel,labelsep=period}
```

#### Change format in both caption label and references

If you want the table *counter* to have the format "L-1" as well, you can simply use `\renewcommand{\thetable}{L-\arabic{table}}` as in the below MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}

\renewcommand{\thetable}{L-\arabic{table}}
\captionsetup[table]{labelfont=bf, labelsep=period}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{This is a table caption}
\begin{tabular}{@{} lcccccc @{}} % suppress horizontal whitespace at start and end
\end{tabular}
\label{labelhere}
\end{table}

In text: Table \ref{labelhere}

\end{document}
```

which gives the output

> [image: Output]

Comment: It worked well but I tried to refer caption name in text. It does not show "L-1". It only show "1". For example "Tabel \ref{Table L-1}". In which Table L-1 is label of the tabel. The output is Tabel 1, instead of Tabel L-1.

Comment: @user8430 Please see edited answer.