# Different autoref titles depending on file of origin (xr package)

Tags: cross-referencing

I am using package **xr** to produce scientific manuscript. I have main and Supplementary file and want to use `\autoref` to provide reference to figures. However, when I use reference to figure which is in the main text I want it to appear as "In Figure 2 we have ... ", but for the figures which are placed in Supplementary file I want it to appear as "In Supplementary Figure". In other words, I want "`In \autoref{fig:secondFigure} we have ..."` to provide different outputs, depending on in which file figure with label `fig:secondFigure` resides. Is it possible to do this and how?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301347/table-caption-label-format-as-table-l-1 can help you? In your case the `\renewcommand` should not go at the top, but at the start of the supplementary material.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Can you please post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Currently we have to guess what packages etc you are using and this makes it really hard to help you. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. It is much easier to help if we have close to working code to start from.