# change Figure 1.1 for Figure 1-1

Tags: formatting, captions

Default setting of the Latex shows:

> Figure 1.1. Caption....

I want to change the format to

> Fig 1-1(without dot here) Caption

How can I change it similarily for tabel

A related question :[How to change Figure 1: to bold Fig.1. in latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/276796/189902)

the  minimal example is :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.62\linewidth]{flow}
            \caption{}
            \label{}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[trim = 15mm 0mm 0mm 0mm, clip=true, width=8.5cm]{2.png}}
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[trim = 15mm 0mm 0mm 0mm, clip=true, width=8.5cm]{1.png}}
    \caption{}\label{}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That, in general, will depend on the document class and packages that you are using. Please add a short, minimal example document so that the answer can adapt to your case.

Comment: thank you I have added more information

Comment: It's called Minimal WORKING Example for a reason. Nonetheless see [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301347/table-caption-label-format-as-table-l-1). Possible duplicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}

\renewcommand\thefigure{\thesection-\arabic{figure}} % the counter style
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont={bf},name={Fig},labelsep=space} % other settings

\begin{document}
\section{This is a real MWE}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.62\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Foo}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \subfloat[foo]{\includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
    \subfloat[boo]{\includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
    \caption{Lipsum}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I have made some edits so it can be compiled.

The result:
[image: Result]

> **Tip**: Do make the MWE compilable. For images, `example-image` and others can be a good choice.